# gnome terminal not piping output to file correctly bash script

Tags: linux, bash, gnome, gnome-terminal

I'm trying to open a new terminal window run a program and output that to a file. This is the code I'm using when i run it it opens a new terminal and runs it correctly but never pipes the output to the file.

```
./my-router topology.txt A | tee -a outputA.txt
```

If i run the above code it will run correctly and output to a file.

```
gnome-terminal -e "./my-router topology.txt A | tee -a outputA.txt";
```

If i run just the above code it will open a new terminal and run but not output. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
#!/bin/bash

gnome-terminal -e "./my-router topology.txt A | tee -a outputA.txt";
gnome-terminal -e "./my-router topology.txt B | tee -a outputB.txt";
gnome-terminal -e "./my-router topology.txt C | tee -a outputC.txt";
gnome-terminal -e "./my-router topology.txt D | tee -a outputD.txt";
gnome-terminal -e "./my-router topology.txt E | tee -a outputE.txt";
gnome-terminal -e "./my-router topology.txt F | tee -a outputF.txt";
```

Comment: what linux version are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do it like this

`gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c "./my-router topology.txt 2>&1 | tee outputA.txt"`'